# Warning in Open testing apk for Content not readable. Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-play-console

**Warnings in Playstore**

This application is already live and I'm updating the app regularly but last time I got 9 warnings with more than 700 screenshots.

And they also send a recommendation

**Recommendation**

This item may not have a label readable by screen readers. [Learn More](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7158690)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Accessibility support in your app.

> For mobile, screen readers (TalkBack, VoiceOver) enable visually impaired users to get spoken feedback about the contents of the screen and interact with the UI via gestures on mobile and keyboard shortcuts on desktop. Turn on VoiceOver or TalkBack on your mobile device and navigate around your app.

You can Ignore this warning.

> Flutter’s standard widgets generate an accessibility tree automatically. However, if your app needs something different, it can be customized using the Semantics widget.